# ASN1 global constraints

Tags: asn.1

Below module has **sKeyPkgAttrs** (global) and **SKeyAttributes** (local). I want to add some attributes into these. If an attribute is present in sKeyPkgAttrs, then it MUST NOT be present in SKeyAttributes - and vice versa.

Some of my attributes are OPTIONAL and some MUST BE present in this module.

**Question**: Is it possible to constrain this module in a way that it checks if an attribute appeared in one of the above, so it can't be put in the other? And if an attribute appeard at all (when it's a MUST BE)

**For example**:

- I put the same attributes in sKeyPkgAttrs and SKeyAttributes - all as OPTIONAL
- constrain "WITH COMPONENT" checks whether at least one attribute is present
- some other constrain check if attributes do not duplicate
- some other constrain check if MUST BE attributes are present

```
SymmetricKeyPackage ::= SEQUENCE {
   version           KeyPkgVersion DEFAULT v1,
   sKeyPkgAttrs  [0] SEQUENCE SIZE (1..MAX) OF Attribute
                                  {{ SKeyPkgAttributes }} OPTIONAL,
   sKeys             SymmetricKeys,
   ... }

 SymmetricKeys ::= SEQUENCE SIZE (1..MAX) OF OneSymmetricKey

 OneSymmetricKey ::= SEQUENCE {
   sKeyAttrs  SEQUENCE SIZE (1..MAX) OF Attribute
                                     {{ SKeyAttributes }} OPTIONAL,
   sKey       OCTET STRING OPTIONAL }
   ( WITH COMPONENTS { ..., sKeyAttrs PRESENT } |
     WITH COMPONENTS { ..., sKey PRESENT } )

 KeyPkgVersion ::= INTEGER  { v1(1) } ( v1, ... )

 SKeyPkgAttributes ATTRIBUTE ::= { ... }

 SKeyAttributes ATTRIBUTE ::= { ... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to place a constraint on SymmetricKeyPackage itself.  Unfortunately, ASN.1 does not have constraint for the kind of uniqueness checking that I believe you are looking for.  ASN.1 does allow what is called a user constraint as follows:

```
SymmetricKeyPackage ::= SEQUENCE {
   version           KeyPkgVersion DEFAULT v1,
   sKeyPkgAttrs  [0] SEQUENCE SIZE (1..MAX) OF Attribute
                                  {{ SKeyPkgAttributes }} OPTIONAL,
   sKeys             SymmetricKeys,
   ... } (CONSTRAINED BY {-- comment describing constraint --})
```

Some ASN.1 Tools will just ignore this constraint, but some ASN.1 Tools will create a function stub in which you can write your own code to enforce this kind of constraint that goes beyond the built-in capabilities of the ASN.1 constraint notation.  Obviously you need to replace -- comment describing constraint -- with a complete description of the constraint you are trying to impose.